# Submitting results to Kaggle competition from command line regardless of kernel type or file name, in or out of Kaggle

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

Within Kaggle: How can I submit my results to Kaggle competition regardless of kernel type or file name?

And if I am in a notebook outside Kaggle (Colab, Jupyter, Paperspace, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Introduction (you can skip this part)

I was looking around for a method to do that. In particular, being able to submit at any point within the notebook (so you can test different approaches), a file with any name (to keep things separated), and any number of times (respecting the Kaggle limitations).

I found many webs explaining the process like

```
Making Submission
1. Hit the "Publish" button at the top of your notebook screen.
If you have written an output file, then you have an "Output" tab.
2. Output > Submit to Competition
```

However they fail to clarify that the Kernel must be of type "Script" and not "Notebook".

That has some limitations that I haven't fully explored.

I just wanted to be able to submit whatever file from the notebook, just like any other command within it.

---

#### The process

Well, here is the process I came up with.

Suggestions, errors, comments, improvements are welcome. Specifically I'd like to know why this method is no better than the one described above.

*Process:*

0. Install required libraries
1. Provide your kaggle credentials

- using the file kaggle.json OR
- setting some environment variables with your kaggle credentials

2. Submit with a simple command.

---

Q: Where do I get my kaggle credentials?

A: You get them from https://www.kaggle.com > 'Account' > "Create new API token"

---

#### 1. Install required libraries

```
# Install required libraries
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install kaggle --upgrade
```

---

#### 2. Provide your kaggle credentials -- setting some environment variables with your kaggle credentials

```
# Add your PRIVATE credentials
# Do not use "!export KAGGLE_USERNAME= ..." OR "" around your credential
%env KAGGLE_USERNAME=abc
%env KAGGLE_KEY=12341341

# Verify
!export -p | grep KAGGLE_USERNAME
!export -p | grep KAGGLE_KEY
```

See **Note** below.

---

#### 2. Provide your kaggle credentials -- using the file kaggle.json

```
%mkdir --parents /root/.kaggle/
%cp /kaggle/input/<your_private_dataset>/kaggle.json   /root/.kaggle/
!chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

How you get the file there is up to you.

One simple way is this:

1. Download the kaggle.json to your computer
2. In kaggle, create a private dataset (Your_Profile > Datasets > New Dataset)
3. Add the kaggle.json to that Dataset
4. Add the private Dataset to your notebook ( Data > Add Data > Datasets > Your Datasets)

This may seem a bit cumbersome, but soon or later your API credentials may change and updating the file in one point (the dataset) will update it in all your notebooks.

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/kaggle-user-content/o/inbox%2F2980069%2Ff5b3b58ea30492c591f6e410d210d02a%2F2020-03-29--11-54.png?generation=1585475906897442&alt=media))</sub>

---

#### 3. Submit with a simple command.

Here `<competition-name>` is the code name of the competition. You can get it from the url of the competition or from the section "My submissions" within the competition page.

[image]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/kaggle-user-content/o/inbox%2F2980069%2F53d8fa751f81bb0baba8d52798d04973%2F2020-03-29--12-08.png?generation=1585479334901171&alt=media))</sub>

```
# Submit
!kaggle competitions submit -c <competition-name> -f submission.csv -m "Notes"
# example:
!kaggle competitions submit -c bike-sharing-demand -f submission.csv -m "Notes"

# View results
!kaggle competitions submissions -c <competition-name>
# example:
!kaggle competitions submissions -c bike-sharing-demand
```

---

**Note:**
If you are too conscious about security of your credentials and/or want to share the kernel, then you can type the 2 commands with your credentials on the "**Console**" instead of within the notebook (example below). They will be valid/available during that session only.

```
import os
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = "here DO use double quotes"
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = "here DO use double quotes"
```

You can find the console at the bottom of your kernel.

[image]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/kaggle-user-content/o/inbox%2F2980069%2F5a6c0b1d66031b724345eee8d957e288%2F2020-03-29--12-55.png?generation=1585479388066417&alt=media))</sub>

---

PS: Initially this was posted [here](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/101395), but when the answer grew the Markdown display breaks in Kaggle (not in other places), therefore I had to take it out of Kaggle.